# What's the meaning of this ideogram?

Tags: translation, meaning

Anyone can tell me the meaning of the picture's ideogram?

[image: Ideogram]

Comment: Hello Detry, welcome to Chinese SE! Have you tried translating the sentence yourself? Please provide any effort in the future, so we know you at least tried. Your question can be reopened if you edit it to add the missing context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to make a wild guess here, the picture looks like the simplified character of 壽 (**寿**)

This character is often seen during Chinese new year, where people wish others a long life, for ex. 祝人長壽, 萬年長壽

From the picture, it looks like it's carved on a rock, these are often seen in souvenir shops that sell small trinkets with Chinese characters.